# When does Arrow S04E19 occur in relation to The Flash?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, arrow

At the end of Arrow S04E19 we see that

> Barry still has his speed, when he runs off after Oliver says "I want to be alone".

So where does this Arrow episode occur in time, in relation to the Flash? Because as of The Flash S02E18's ending we know that

> Barry no longer has any speed force, Zoom siphoned it in exchange for Wally West.

So where does this episode of Arrow occur in relation to the CW-verse timeline?

Comment: 0
down vote
I was thinking the same thing since the start of the series the crossovers have been in chronological order,but now either they launched the arrow too late or the flash needed a double episode where flash gets some magic fluid or something.

Comment: The crossovers have not always been chronological. Last year had a crossover where the relationship status of Felicity and Ray was out of sync.

Comment: Yes but there was a tell in those episodes to indicate what order they were, this one is just confusing!

Answer (score 1):

In S04E01 of Arrow, saw the timeline of the end of the season, which is six months past the ending of S04E18 of Arrow, which also occurs concurrently with the recent episodes is S02 of Flash. Therefore, it could be safely assumed that the last episodes in each shows reflect roughly the same timeline, i.e. 6 months after S04E18 of Arrow, so six months from the current time.

Hopefully this made some sense because it confused the hell out of me. But essentially, I think we can assume the events of the new episodes will explain things that occurred over the last six months.

Comment: What I meant was that, following standard "flash -> arrow" timings, Barry should not have had his speed at the funeral. because in the Flash episode of this week.

I know that we are roughly 6 months past S04E01. What I asked was, where did this Arrow Episode fit into time, in regards to the Flash episode from the same week.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing answer. Hopefully the next episode of Flash will clear things up.