# What was going on with Oliver Queen and Flash at the graveyard?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, arrow

At the start of Season 4 of *Arrow*, we see a flash-forward teaser scene: Oliver Queen at a grave.  The Flash shows up and apologizes for not being able to help out, and Oliver says he understands, because Flash was busy with his own villain.  Flash nods and runs off at his customary super-speed.

However, by the time the story catches up to this point,

> The Flash has been depowered.

This would seem to indicate that this *Arrow* episode is taking place further ahead of the storyline for *The Flash.*  In *Rupture*, the *The Flash* episode that aired immediately after this *Arrow* episode, though, two things happen to cast doubt on this interpretation:

At the beginning of *Rupture*, we see that Cisco has

> rigged some STAR Labs satellite technology to project a holographic image of The Flash, to help make people think he's still around and provide what assistance he can to the police this way.  However, I'm disinclined to believe that it was a hologram talking with Oliver, because he was was *talking with Oliver,* in a fully interactive, normal conversation.

Second, at the end of *Rupture*,

> something goes wrong and Barry appears to die horribly by disintegration.  He has not gotten his powers back at this point.

In light of this, when does the graveyard scene take place, and what's Barry's status?  Do we have any official answer so far?

Comment: Dupe: [When does Arrow S04E19 occur in relation to The Flash?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/126427/5184)

Comment: It can't have been a hologram. Wells specifically mentions that people would eventually realize it wasn't the Flash because the hologram could never talk, touch anything, or go inside a building.